# How to find wifi password in user binary without rooting the device

Tags: passwords, wifi, backup, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am working on an app that would take backup of the phone to be restored in another phone. I am stuck in wifi password backing up part. I would like to know if there is an way to find wifi password from a non rooted device. If I query wifi manager I would get * and not the password. Is there any work around to get the wifi password through code.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this can help you to get wifi password easily but you have to install linux for that http://www.arhixe.com/?p=530